# center nav logo remove parent div click funtion

Tags: css

I am trying to accomplish  the following, but for some reason I cannot get the image to stay in the center just as the layout below.

the issue is the whole div even the logo is clickable, I only want the icon clickable.

I also want the logo to remain in the center with the menu icon in the exact same place as the image below.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".mobile-menu").on('click', function(){
  $(".mobile-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
 });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo{
 display: inline-block;
}

.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link{
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000000;
}

.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link i{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

.mobile-dropdown {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 125px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile-dropdown li{
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.mobile-dropdown li a{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-dropdown li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #00adef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="mobile-menu">
  <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/65x65">
  <a class="dropdown-link">&#9776;</a>
  <ul class="mobile-dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Uw specialist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oplossingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Greatest care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Budget smart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the markup you currently have you can just position the logo absolutely. Use `left:0`, `right:0` and `margin:auto` to center it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown-link").on('click', function(){
  $(".mobile-dropdown").slideToggle("fast");
 });
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu {
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  background:black;
}

.logo{
 display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:7px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}

.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link{
  display: block;
  height: 80px; width:80px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000000;
}

.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.mobile-menu a.dropdown-link i{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: 15px;
}

.mobile-dropdown {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 125px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile-dropdown li{
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.mobile-dropdown li a{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-dropdown li a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #00adef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="mobile-menu">
  <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/65x65">
  <a class="dropdown-link">&#9776;</a>
  <ul class="mobile-dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Uw specialist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oplossingen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Greatest care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Budget smart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the whole div is still clickable

Comment: @Codi there you go.